# "1 голос" нужен вместо "1 голоса"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При подтверждении правки вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Исправлено в [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261902?key=7381dafcd65d48fca94366a3726f7c37). Вариант для **one** выглядит теперь так:

> Чтобы утвердить данное предложение, необходимо чтобы проголосовал ещё $numVotes$ участник. Для продолжения, закройте это всплывающее окно (или нажмите Esc).

Comment: "ещё 1 голос" верно, а "ещё 2 голос" неверно, плюс слова "необходим(о)" и "обозревателя(-ей)". Должны отвергнуть.

Comment: @edem это вариант именно для случая единственного голоса. Есть и другие строки (для иного кол-ва).

Comment: Если так, то да, пойдёт.

Comment: Может, тогда не обращаться к `numVotes`, а захардкодить единицу?

Comment: @NewDevelop была такая мысль, но т.к. в исходной строке уже была переменная, то решил оставить.