# Опечатки в сообщении после первого принятия предложенной правки

Tags: дефект, локализация

### 1. Шаги для воспроизведения

Пользователь с рейтингом меньше 2000 предложил правку → в вопросе это отражается символами `(1)` рядом со словом «править» →

[image: Единица]

проверяющий правку нажимает на «править» → принимает правку → появляется сообщение:

[image: Принятие]

> Чтобы утвердить данное предложение, необходимо чтобы проголосовал ещё 1 участник. Для продолжения, закройте это всплывающее окно (или нажмите Esc).

---

### 2. Опечатки

1. Полагаю, что между «необходимо» и «чтобы» нужна запятая, разделяющая части сложноподчинённого предложения.
2. Считаю, что между словами «продолжения» и «закройте» запятая не требуется — оборот с предлогом «для» не относится к случаям, когда должно происходить обособление. [**Обсуждение вопроса в сообществе KORREKTOR_RU**](http://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/933896.html).

---

### 3. Дополнительная ссылка

[**Здесь**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3732/199934) обсуждался данный вопрос, однако в итоговом варианте остались опечатки.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю несколько упростить перевод основной части и сделать так:

- one

  > Для утверждения данного предложения необходим голос ещё $numVotes$ участника.
- few / many

  > Для утверждения данного предложения необходимы голоса ещё $numVotes$ участников.

Во втором предложении убрать запятую, как рекомендует ТС:

> Для продолжения закройте это всплывающее окно (или нажмите Esc).

[Оригинальная строка](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261902?key=7381dafcd65d48fca94366a3726f7c37) на всякий случай:

> This suggestion still needs $numVotes$ approve votes from other reviewers. Close this popup (or hit Esc) to continue.

Также нужно согласовать с вариантом [текста для отклонения](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261905?key=ac7762098eb159beab55ccce91896d6b):

- оригинал

  > This suggestion still needs $numVotes$ reject votes from other reviewers. Close this popup (or hit Esc) to continue.
- перевод для one (в качестве примера)

  > Для отклонения данного предложения необходим ещё $numVotes$ голос другого обозревателя. Для продолжения, закройте это всплывающее окно (или нажмите Esc).

Comment: "ещё один голос другого проверяющего" на мой взгляд лучше

Comment: @vp_arth я уже думаю, что возможно стоит отдельную тему открыть по улучшению перевода дабы рассмотреть возможные варианты. А здесь просто пофиксить замечания ТС и закрыть.

Comment: Оккама против. Давайте тут всё и решим

Comment: Цитата "для отклонения" норм же(кроме запятой) - её и конвертировать в остальные 5.

Comment: alexolut, возмжно, другие и не сочтут это за тавтологию, но я бы не повторял без необходимости предлог «для». Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных это как в итоге будет?

Comment: alexolut, например, просто поправить запятые в оригинале. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных но это не согласуется с вариантом отклонения правки. Пожалуйста.

Comment: alexolut, также пишем «Чтобы отклонить данное предложение ...». Что именно не согласуется? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных мне не очень нравится такой вариант. Пожалуйста.

Comment: @alexolut переведено же? В [meta-tag:статус-завершено] го?