# Сообщение о принятии/отклонении предложенной правки

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, предлагаемые-правки

Вопрос [Опечатки в сообщении после первого принятия предложенной правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4937/176217) выявил необходимость привести к единому виду сообщения при отклонении/утверждении предложенной правки.

Исходные сообщения выглядят так:

- [approve](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261902?key=7381dafcd65d48fca94366a3726f7c37)

  > This suggestion still needs $numVotes$ approve votes from other reviewers. Close this popup (or hit Esc) to continue.
- [reject](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261905?key=ac7762098eb159beab55ccce91896d6b)

  > This suggestion still needs $numVotes$ reject votes from other reviewers. Close this popup (or hit Esc) to continue.

Текущий перевод существенно отличается для данных сообщений (для примера покажу только вариант **one**):

- approve

  > Чтобы утвердить данное предложение, необходимо чтобы проголосовал ещё $numVotes$ участник. Для продолжения, закройте это всплывающее окно (или нажмите Esc).
- reject

  > Для отклонения данного предложения необходим ещё $numVotes$ голос другого обозревателя. Для продолжения, закройте это всплывающее окно (или нажмите Esc).

Хорошо бы эти переводы привести к единому виду. Предлагайте свои варианты или голосуйте за существующие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю следующие варианты:

- approve

  - one

    > Для утверждения данного предложения необходим голос ещё $numVotes$ участника.
  - few / many

    > Для утверждения данного предложения необходимы голоса ещё $numVotes$ участников.
- reject

  - one

    > Для отклонения данного предложения необходим голос ещё $numVotes$ участника.
  - few / many

    > Для отклонения данного предложения необходимы голоса ещё $numVotes$ участников.

Во втором предложении убрать запятую, как предлагает [Саша Черных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) в упомянутом ранее вопросе.

> Для продолжения закройте это всплывающее окно (или нажмите Esc).

P.S.
Для вариантов **one** в принципе должно быть можно использовать слово "одного" вместо числа "1". Использовать слово "проверяющий" (как предложено в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4937/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#comment18003_4938)) не вижу особого смысла, т.к. участник в данном контексте и так им является.

**Утвердил на transifex. Всем спасибо за проявленную активность.**